# GetTempFileName throwing 'System.AccessViolationException' vb.net

Tags: vb.net, kernel32

I am new to VB and is working on VB6 to VB.net migration. There is one API call which appends a prefix in temporary file name.

I have added the dll as

```
<DllImport("kernel32")> _
Private Shared Function GetTempFileName(ByVal lpszPath As String, ByVal lpPrefixString As String, ByVal wUnique As Long, ByVal lpTempFileName As String) As Long
End Function
```

When I am calling this:

```
test = GetTempFileName(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, Prefix, 0, m_sTempfile)
```

It throws an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Forum.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I tried using Path.GetTempFileName() but I might need to perform several manipulation to get the file name prefixed with specific word and located to specific location.
I crossed checked the values and they are NOT bad data.
I tried mutiple resolutions, but none of it worked. 
Can someone help in this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: in NET use `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()` and get rid of the PInvoke

Comment: Since my requirement is : Need to create a temp file with a specific prefix and to be created in specific location, I have to manipulate the GetTempFileName(), or do we have methods for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinvoke declarations need to be rewritten when you move them to VB.NET.  Many differences, like Long needs to be Integer and if the winapi function returns a string then you need to use StringBuilder instead of String.  Required because String is an immutable type.

Proper declaration is:

```
<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function GetTempFileName(ByVal lpszPath As String, _
                                       ByVal lpPrefixString As String, _
                                       ByVal wUnique As Integer, _
                                       ByVal lpTempFileName As StringBuilder) As Integer
End Function
```

And a proper call looks like:

```
    Dim buffer As New StringBuilder(260)
    If GetTempFileName("c:\temp", "xyz", 0, buffer) = 0 Then
        Throw New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception()
    End If
    Dim filename = buffer.ToString()
```

The pinvoke.net website tends to be a half-decent resource for pinvoke declarations.  Not for this one though, the VB.NET version is pretty fumbled.

Comment: Perfect!
The issue was using Long. When change to integer, it worked like a charm!
Thanks Hans Passant!

Comment: Hmm, no, using a String for the 4th argument was the most serious problem.  You just didn't get a chance to corrupt the GC heap yet.  An AVE is a good problem to have, you know you're doing it wrong.  Heap corruption is the silent killer.  Don't skip that change.

Comment: Added the string builder! Thanks Hans for the suggestion!